# Erro ao executar aplicação com interface gráfica no Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu

Erro ao executar aplicação com interface gráfica no Python 3.

```
File "/home/nexide/PycharmProjects/untitled1/.idea/testew.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Estou usando o python 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```